# How do I return value from javascript function through Awesomium library?

Tags: javascript, .net, awesomium

I am trying to return an javascript value with Awesome lib in Vb.net / C#. Now I know how to execute

```
WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript("func_name")
```

but how do I return value?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [ExecuteJavascriptWithResult](http://awesomium.com/docs/1_6_3/sharp_api/html/53d0c7c4-7590-dfac-1649-e28bf4697d9f.htm):

```
string sResult = WebControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("func_name");
```